# Change registry permissions via command line (batch file)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry, acl

I found an [awesome Reg Hack](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_computer_name_localizedstring.htm) for Windows 7, that renames the 'Computer' icon to something like `%username% on %computername%`. Unfortunately, in the tutorial, it says to change permissions of the registry key. I would like to change this from the command line, in a batch file, then add that tweak, then lock down that key again, all in one file. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Similar question: https://serverfault.com/questions/331046/change-permissions-on-registry-key-via-command-line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found my way around another utility, [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/download/). I pushed the file out to some systems, then ran the following commands  remotely. They succeeded, and the icon changed on those systems after doing an <kbd>F5</kbd> on the Desktop.

```
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr n:Administrators
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:Administrators;p:full"
reg import computername.reg
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Subinacl.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/subinacl.html) (Official tool from Microsoft for managing permissions).

To change users permissions for a special registery key and its subkeys you can write sommething like this (copy the Subinacl.exe file in C:\Cindows\system32 to use it directly as a standard command in cmd ):

```
> subinacl.exe /subkeyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\POLICIES\MICROSOFT /grant=Everyone=f
```

Comment: Last Syntax Error:WARNING : /grant=everyone=f : Error when checking arguments - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\POLICIES\MICROSOFT

Comment: Hi I just checked the code and it worked fine. In the output you get sometthing like --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\POLICIES\MICROSOFT\SystemCertificates\TrustedPublisher\Certificates : 1 change(s)
--> SOFTWARE\POLICIES\MICROSOFT\SystemCertificates\TrustedPublisher\CRLs : new ace for \everyone
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\POLICIES\MICROSOFT\SystemCertificates\TrustedPublisher\CRLs : 1 change(s)
You should check if you put the spaces correctly between the exe, the parameters etc.